# Doctrine result cache not caching a query with a join

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I'm using Doctrine 2.2.2 trying to do a query for a user entity along with the user's company.  I want this query to be cached since the data inside won't change often, if at all.  Below is what I've tried:

```
$user = $em->createQuery('
    SELECT u, c
    FROM Entities\User u
    LEFT JOIN u.company c
    WHERE u.id = :id
')->setParameter('id', $identity)->useResultCache(true, 21600, 'user_' . $identity)->getResult();
```

Seemingly, the user entity is cached, but it still does a query for the company.  Is there a way I can fetch both at the same time and have them be placed into the result cache?

I did find [this](http://shout.setfive.com/2010/04/28/using-doctrine-result-cache-with-two-deep-relations/), but it's very old and his solution did not work for me.

It was suggested to me that I do [this](https://gist.github.com/4060861), but that kind of defeats the purpose of the result cache.

Comment: i dont know doctrine, but you can give mysql internal cache a try: SELECT SQL_CACHE u, c
    FROM Entities\User u
    LEFT JOIN u.company c
    WHERE u.id = :id

Comment: That is not helpful.  I want to be able to use all of the Doctrine entity things.

Comment: Try enforce EAGER fetching (instead of lazy). You have to add fetch="EAGER" to your relation definition.

Comment: I have tried that as well.  No dice.

Comment: as statet in the docs here: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/caching.html#result-cache you don´t have to enable the cache explicitly as long as a cache is set to the query. Did you actually specifiy a cache and which one?

Comment: I tried using the APC cache driver.  As stated, it did work, but only for the first entity.  It did not follow the relationships.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested this with Doctrine 2.3 using:

```
$q->setResultCacheDriver( new \Doctrine\Common\Cache\ApcCache() )
  ->setResultCacheLifetime( 21600 )
  ->setResultCacheId( 'user_' . $identity );
```

When I run it the first time, I see the actual query in my sql-logger.

When I run it the second, third, etc time, I don't see anything in my sql-logger.

My conclusion is it's working fine.

I guess you either haven't got a result-cache configured, or you have a non-permanent result-cache (like ArrayCache) configured, or it's a bug in Dontrine 2.2.2 (although I can't find anything about it on jira).

PS: I gather from another question ([Doctrine detaching, caching, and merging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13372305/doctrine-detaching-caching-and-merging)) that you've upgraded to Doctrine 2.3. Do you still have this problem?

PPS: Somewhere after Doctrine 2.0 (I think it was 2.2), the result-cache changed. In stead of caching the hydrated result, the sql-result is cached (and hydration takes place every run). If you want to cache the hydrated result, you'll have to use the hydration-cache (but be ware that those results are **not** merged into the EntityManager).

Comment: My solution to this was to create my own "result cache".  That's what the other question is about.