# Doctrine detaching, caching, and merging

Tags: php, doctrine, doctrine-orm

I'm on Doctrine 2.3.  I have the following query:

```
$em->createQuery('
    SELECT u, c, p
    FROM Entities\User u
    LEFT JOIN u.company c
    LEFT JOIN u.privilege p
    WHERE u.id = :id
')->setParameter('id', $identity)
```

I then take that, get the result (which is an array, I just take the first element), and run detach `$em->detach($result);`.

When I go to fetch from the cache (using Doctrine's APC cache driver), I do:

```
$cacheDriver = new \Doctrine\Common\Cache\ApcCache();
if($cacheDriver->contains($cacheId))
{
    $entity = $cacheDriver->fetch($cacheId);
    $em->merge($entity);
    return $entity;
}
```

My hope was that this would re-enable the relationship loading on the entity as there are many other relationships tied to the User object other than what's shown in that query.

I'm trying to create a new entity like such:

```
$newEntity = new Entities\ClientType();
$newEntity['param'] = $data;
$newEntitiy['company'] = $this->user['company'];
$em->persist($newEntity);
$em->flush();
```

When I do this, I get an error:

```
A new entity was found through the relationship 'Entities\ClientType#company' that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity:
Entities\Company@000000005d7b49b500000000dd7ad743. 
To solve this issue: Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on this unknown entity or configure cascade persist this association in the mapping for example @ManyToOne(..,cascade={"persist"}). 
If you cannot find out which entity causes the problem implement 'Entities\Company#__toString()' to get a clue.
```

This works just fine when I don't use the company entity under the user entity that I got from cache.  Is there any way to make this work so I don't have to refetch the company entity from the database every time I want to use it in a relationship with a new entity?

**Edit:**
This is what I have in my User entity dealing with these two relationships:

```
/**
    * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Company" , inversedBy="user", cascade={"detach", "merge"})
    */
    protected $company;

    /**
    * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Privilege" , inversedBy="user", cascade={"detach", "merge"})
    */
    protected $privilege;
```

I am still getting the same error.

**Second edit:**
Trying a `$em->contains($this->user);` and `$em->contains($this->user['company']);` both return false.  Which sounds... wrong.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When merging a User, you want the associated Company and Privilege to be merged as well, correct?

This process is called cascading:

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#transitive-persistence-cascade-operations

In your User entity put `cascade={"merge"}` in the `@ManyToOne` annotation (or another type of association-definition you are using) for `$company` and `$privilege`.

And if you want the detach call to be cascaded too (which is recommended), put in `cascade={"detach", "merge"}`.

p.s.: Don't put such cascades on both sides of one association, you'll create an endless loop ;)

**Edit:**

This piece of code:

```
$entity = $cacheDriver->fetch($cacheId);
$em->merge($entity);                      // <-
return $entity;
```

should be:

```
$entity = $cacheDriver->fetch($cacheId);
$entity = $em->merge($entity);            // <-
return $entity;
```

The thing with `merge()` is that it leaves the entity you pass as an argument untouched, and returns a **new** object that represents the managed version of the entity. So you want to use the return-value, not the argument you passed.

Comment: Privilege is actually a relationship with the user.  So it would need the `cascade={"detach", "merge"}` on both the company and privilege relationships, correct?

Comment: Please see my update.  Putting cascade seems to have had no effect.

Comment: Hi, I know this is an old post, but I found a problem with this approach. I set all as you explained, but I noticed on doctrine's logs  that it tries to update also the entity merged returned with the same values that are in database. How to avoid this? I've used cascade={"detach", "merge"} as cascade. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Np, but could you ask a new question about this? You're describing a different issue.

Comment: Here we are :) Thanks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23519983/doctrine-2-how-to-use-objects-retrieved-from-cache-in-relationships

Comment: It took me a whole day untit I read the last paragraph of this question. Scan reading can be bad sometimes. :( So I created a question on this subject specifically to help someone else with the same problem. Here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27321682/associated-entity-not-merged-correctly/27321727#27321727