# Doctrine 2 - How to use objects retrieved from cache in relationships

Tags: php, symfony, caching, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm working in a project that use Doctrine 2 in Symfony 2 and I use MEMCACHE to store doctrine's results.
I have a problem with objects that are retrieved from MEMCACHE.

I found this post similar, but this approach not resolves my problem: [Doctrine detaching, caching, and merging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13372305/doctrine-detaching-caching-and-merging)

This is the scenario

```
/**
 * This is in entity ContestRegistry
 * @var contest
 * 
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Contest", inversedBy="usersRegistered")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="contest_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE"))
 *
 */
protected $contest;
```

and in other entity

```
 /**
 * @var usersRegistered
 * 
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ContestRegistry", mappedBy="contest")
 *
 */
protected $usersRegistered;
```

Now imagine that Contest is in cache and I want to save a ContestRegistry entry.
So I retrieve the object contest in cache as follows:

```
$contest = $cacheDriver->fetch($key);
$contest = $this->getEntityManager()->merge($contest);
return $contest;
```

And as last operation I do:

```
$contestRegistry = new ContestRegistry();
$contestRegistry->setContest($contest);
$this->entityManager->persist($contestRegistry);
$this->entityManager->flush();
```

My problem is that doctrine saves the new entity correctly, but also it makes an update on the entity Contest and it updates the column updated. The real problem is that it makes an update query for every entry, I just want to add a reference to the entity.
How I can make it possible?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Why**

When an entity is merged back into the EntityManager, it will be marked as dirty. This means that when a flush is performed, the entity will be updated in the database. This seems reasonable to me, because when you make an entity *managed*, you actually want the EntityManager to manage it ;)

In your case you only need the entity for an association with another entity, so you don't really need it to be *managed*. I therefor suggest a different approach.

**Use a reference**

So don't merge `$contest` back into the EntityManager, but grab a reference to it:

```
$contest    = $cacheDriver->fetch($key);
$contestRef = $em->getReference('Contest', $contest->getId());

$contestRegistry = new ContestRegistry();
$contestRegistry->setContest($contestRef);

$em->persist($contestRegistry);
$em->flush();
```

That reference will be a Proxy (unless it's already *managed*), and won't be loaded from the db at all (not even when flushing the EntityManager).

**Result Cache**

In stead of using you own caching mechanisms, you could use Doctrine's [result cache](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/caching.html#result-cache). It caches the query results in order to prevent a trip to the database, but (if I'm not mistaken) still hydrates those results. This prevents a lot of issues that you can get with caching entities themselves.

Comment: Hi, I tried both the solutions and the first doesn't work. I don't know why. With reference it works. Maybe when I change the tracking policy, I should modify all the entities involved in a relationship?

Comment: I've looked into that, and it seems the entity is marked as dirty regardless of the change tracking policy. So that's not an option here. I've updated my answer.

Comment: BTW: I do recommend using _Deferred Explicit_ for _all_ your entities, because flushes become a lot cheaper. Imagine you loaded 5000 entities and changed 1, _Deferred Implicit_ will check all 5000, _Deferred Explicit_ will only check the 1 you called `$em->persist()` on.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to achieve is called partial update.
You should use something like this instead

```
/**
 * Partially updates an entity
 *
 * @param Object $entity The entity to update
 * @param Request $request
 */
protected function partialUpdate($entity, $request)
{
    $parameters = $request->request->all();

    $accessor = PropertyAccess::createPropertyAccessor();
    foreach ($parameters as $key => $parameter) {
        $accessor->setValue($entity, $key, $parameter);
    }
}
```

Merge requires the whole entity to be 100% fullfilled with data.
I haven't checked the behavior with children (many to one, one to one, and so on) relations yet.

Partial update is usually used on PATCH (or PUT) on a Rest API.