# Initializing association from cached entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony4

I've got an issue with using cached Doctrine entities in Symfony 4. When I get a saved entity from the cache, the associations are not initialised and I don't know how I can initialise them.

I have a Product entity (App\Entity\Product) which has an ManyToOne-association with ProductGroup.

This is the non-cached situation. The Product entity has an association with the ProductGroup entity.

```
>> $product = $this->entityManager->getRepository(Product::class)
                   ->find($id); // App\Entity\Product
>> dump($product->getProductGroup());

ProductGroup {#563 ▼
  -id: 3
  -name: "name"
  -title: "title"
  -products: PersistentCollection {#574 ▶}
}
```

Now, when I cache the entry and retrieve it, I get this:

```
>> $cache = new TagAwareAdapter(ApcuAdapter());

>> $cacheItem = $cache->getItem("cache_key");
>> $product = $cacheItem->get(); // App\Entity\Product

>> dump($product->getProductGroup());

ProductGroup {#3369 ▼
  +__isInitialized__: false
  -id: 3
  -name: null
  -title: null
  -products: null
   …2
}
```

As you can see, the (productGroup) entity is not initialized and all parameters except id are not set.

I read that I can solve this by adding `fetch="EAGER"` to the association. However this would mean I would have to eagerly fetch *all* associations from entities I would like to cache.

Is there another solution?

Comment: Why exactly you need the collection to be initialized? If you really need to do that just iterate over the collection (eg. get first item etc.). Also why do you cache a "managed entity"? You should cache a detached object and merge it with the manager after fetching it from the cache store.

Comment: @emix The dump in the second code block is a single entity, not a collection. When I do `dump($product->getProductGroup()->getName());` I get `null` as a response, which is not correct.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Doctrine 2 - How to use objects retrieved from cache in relationships](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23519983/doctrine-2-how-to-use-objects-retrieved-from-cache-in-relationships)

Comment: Agree with the duplicate, however, I'm missing code in the question: how are you caching the record? If you cache an initialized object, it should be initialized (though possibly not managed - can 't recall) when you retrieve it from cache. Can you add how you cache it? And also what you have tried to resolve this? (also, adding `fetch="EAGER"` does not affect cache handling, it's for Doctrine, not something that implements `CacheInterface`).