# Associated entity not merged correctly

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have 2 associated entities like this:

```
class Solicitation {
    <some fields>
    /**
     * @var \User
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", fetch="EAGER", inversedBy="solicitation")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_user", referencedColumnName="id_user", nullable=false)
     * })
     * @OrderBy({"nome" = "ASC"})
     */
    private $user;
    <more fields>
}
```

I don't want to cascade operations. The problem is when I try to merge an existing User before persisting Solicitation, like this:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
if (!(\Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork::STATE_MANAGED === $em->getUnitOfWork()->getEntityState($solicitation->getUser()))) {
    $em->merge($solicitation->getUser());
}
$em->persist($solicitation);
```

...it won't change User UnitOfWork state to "MANAGED". I`ts still "DETACHED" and I receive and error on saving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took me a whole day to find that

```
$em->merge($solicitation->getUser())
```

doesn't change the original entity, it **returns** a menaged entity. So the correct is:

```
$solicitation->setUser($em->merge($solicitation->getUser()));
```

then persist solicitation. Made this question in case someone else needs this.