# Doctrine detaching, caching, and merging part 2

Tags: php, doctrine, doctrine-orm

A while back I asked a couple questions about Doctrine's query cache as it did not work as I wanted it to.

Question about why my relationships weren't being cached:

[Doctrine result cache not caching a query with a join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13336953/doctrine-result-cache-not-caching-a-query-with-a-join)

Question about how to get relationships cached using detaching and merging:

[Doctrine detaching, caching, and merging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13372305/doctrine-detaching-caching-and-merging)

I'm not sure why I didn't do this sooner, but I just enabled Doctrine's `EchoSQLLogger` and I found out that each page is doing three queries when I merge the entities back in.

My entites are `user`, `company`, and `privilege`, with `user` being the parent to the other two.  When I first get the `user` with `company` and `privilege` joined, I run `detach` on the `user` and then put it in `ApcCache`.  When I fetch from cache, I do a `merge` which gives me back the `user` entity with all of the Doctrine magic intact.

The problem is, when I call `merge`, it queries for the `user`, the `company`, and then `privilege`.  Is this how `merge` is supposed to work?

Is there any way to cache my `user` entity with the two relationships intact without making calls to the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone (or myself) reading this in the future:

I ended up working around the `PHP Incomplete Class` issue by doing separate queries and cache saves for each individual entity.  For example my user/company/privilege dilemma in the question.  I cache the user, cache the company and override `$user['company']` with its results, and the same for privilege.

This seems to work, but seriously.  Doctrine's caching needs help.